# Proof that $GL_n, SL_n$ are not bounded

Tags: lie-groups

Please could someone check my work on this exercise (from book I am reading). Thanks!

Exercise:

Prove that $GL_n (\mathbb K)$ is non-compact when $n \ge 1$. Prove that $SL_n (\mathbb K)$ is non-compact when $n \ge 2$. What about $SL_1 (\mathbb K)$?

My solution:

Note that $nI \in GL_n$ and $\|nI\| = n \cdot \sqrt{n}$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean metric hence  $GL_n$ is unbounded.

Let $D_n$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $d_{11} = n, d_{22}={1\over n}$ and $d_{ii}=1$ otherwise. Then $\det D_n = 1$ and $\|D_n\| \ge n$ hence $SL_n$ is unbounded.

$SL_1 (\mathbb R) = \{-1,1\}$ hence is bounded. $SL_1 (\mathbb C) = S^1$ hence is bounded. For the quaternions $\mathbb H$, $SL_1 (\mathbb H) = S^3$ hence is bounded.

Comment: That all looks good to me, at least for the cases you treat. I'm assuming you mean $\Bbb K\in \{\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H\}$?

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes, that's right, $\Bbb K\in \{\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H\}$. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Fyi, since $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb K)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb K)$ the non-boundedness of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb K)$ implies that $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb K)$ is also non-bounded.  So you can ditch the $nI$ example if you want, the $D_n$ example after it suffices.

Comment: @Jim That's right, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Why proving that the groups aren't bounded is enough to prove they aren't compact? Exactly: because you're, apparently, taking the euclidean topology from $\;\Bbb R^{n^2}\;$ (what is $\;\Bbb K\;$ , btw?), so perhaps it'd be worthwhile to mention this.

Comment: @Timbuc Good point, I should mention this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: $SL_1(\mathbb R)$ is not $\{\pm 1\}$; only $\{1\}$.